# How to crop specific areas of a container while preserving the shadow underneath in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose-material3, android-jetpack-compose-canvas

I have a container (Card, Box, or whatever..) that contains two problematic areas, marked with red circles. I need to crop these areas out while ensuring that the shadow underneath is preserved.

[image]

I have tried different approaches, but I couldn't find a solution to crop the areas effectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `.border(width = ..., color = .., CustomShape(...))` modifier with a custom shape. Here is a detailed explanation [Custom Shape with Jetpack Compose](https://juliensalvi.medium.com/custom-shape-with-jetpack-compose-1cb48a991d42)

### The result:

[image]

Comment: Awesome article, thanks a lot. It helped me solve the problem. Cheers :)